# Recovering lost folder name:

Tags: firefox, data-recovery, rename

Can I recover a folder name accidentally lost in renaming?

I've just done a complete installation, formatting everything, from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.

The plan was to slot my Mozilla profile from my backed up copy into the new version, simply renaming the old one, to replace the new .default folder which came with the installation so that Firefox would find my slotted in folder instead. It worked fine on Thunderbird, but on Firefox I somehow accidentally deleted the name of the .default folder I need to replace. This means I don't know what to call the one I'm slotting in. Is there a way, please, of recovering the name I deleted?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Processor AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5200+ × 2 ,Memory 2.0 GiB, OS type 32 bit, Disk 155.3 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you don't need to, if you're going to replace that profile.

The file `.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` contains the path of the default profile:

```
$ ls .mozilla/firefox/
Crash Reports  profiles.ini  wng922jv.default

$ cat .mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini 
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=wng922jv.default
```

So you can either extract the name from the `Path` field above, or, replace it with the path of your profile.

Comment: It works beautifully :-)